# is price of multiple option strategy linear under expectation?

Tags: option-pricing, finance-mathematics, european-options

I wonder if someone can confirm (or refute) that the expected
payoff of several option (in a strategy such as a spread, condor, etc) behaves as *"expection of a sum is sum of expectations".*

Here is my thinking:
First denote $E_m$ = expectation of market at expiration.
(I think is log-normal to a first approximation, but that does not matter for the question).

Then a single option's payout is
$$
  E_m[ f(m) ]
$$
where $f()$ is the function describing a call (or put) payout.

if two options $f_1, f_2$ are added to make a strategy such as a vertical spread, notate the payout
$$
   E_m [ f_1(m) + f_2(m) ]
$$
where $f_1,f_2$ are both functions of the single random variable $m$,
the market value at expiration.

**Now the question:**
Is it true that
$$
   E_m [ f_1(m) + f_2(m) ] = E_m f_1(m) + E_m f_2(m)
$$

Here is an analogy outside of finance (from a reddit discussion), take $f_1(x)=x^2$, $f_2(x)=x^4$.
These functions of a random variable $x$ are clearly are correlated.
however,
$$
   E_x[ x^2 + x^4 ] = \int p(x) (x^2 + x^4) dx  = E_x[x^2] + E_x[x^4]
$$
so they do separate under the expectation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathbf{E}\left[X+Y\right] = \mathbf{E}\left[X\right] + \mathbf{E}\left[Y\right]$$

This is just a property of random variables (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties)).It doesn't matter that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, or correlated.

So yes, when you have a linear combination of derivatives, the value is the linear sum of the values of the individual derivatives.